# TypeScript `undefined` Guard

Tags: typescript

What am I missing here?

This:

```js
interface B { }
interface A {
    b: B | undefined;
}

function f1(a: A) {
    if (a.b) {
        return f2(a);
    }
}
function f2(a: { b: B }) { }
```

Generates:

```
// Errors in code
// 
// Argument of type 'A' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ b: B; }'.
//   Types of property 'b' are incompatible.
//     Type 'B | undefined' is not assignable to type 'B'.
//       Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'B'.
// 'arg' is declared but its value is never read.
```

All the other permutations of that `if` test that I can think of also fail. (Explicitly check for not-`undefined`, invert it and return if `undefined`, etc.)

Playground link:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgELIN7IL4ChSSyIoCCmuylyARgFxrIA+yAriACYQygTsDcuPLhhsEYYAHsQyGAEYAFHHokAlOSrJgMZIoB01NRgoaqUCGBZRpMAEyKVAjXjwiQYydbtLMNeumyGOLi4APQhyACiUFASUADOmtIIEpyh4WnIJFAA5iwAthDgyBLaYACeAA4oAOQk1ZoJIBJgyHBxccDZIHDUADYoYBLIFXBQcAWExaWVNVh0aHw41boZlAAqMwklwzFVUOXI1dT1oyigyXkj4n0QK2EmG1WH6MxsnNwgvPXAjc2t7Z1ujdkIMQTNnstVg9wdU3lweOxvr8Wm0Ol0ev0QUNyk9qqhIfdqqNskjkJwEL1TuwaCwWsAwAkAG5wXosM6NCCM6DIMxwdi6IA

---

So the "non-deterministic getter" suggested by @Etheryte is definitely not a case I thought of.
But TS doesn't seem to really handle *it* well either?
Tweaking to this:

```js
interface B { i: string; }
interface A { b: B | undefined; }

function f1(a: A) {
    if (a.b) {
        return f2(a.b);
    }
}
function f2(b: B) {
    console.log(b.i);
}

const maybeFoo: A = {
    get b() {
        if (Math.random() > 0.5) { return { i: "foo" }; }
        return undefined;
    }
};

// Here's the test!
f1(maybeFoo);
```

That compiles, runs, and (about 1/4 of the time) fails!

```
[ERR]: "Executed JavaScript Failed:" 
[ERR]: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'i') 
[LOG]: "foo"
```

Playground with those tweaks:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=30&ssc=4&pln=23&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgELIN7OALmQZzClAHMBuZAXwChRJZEUBBTZAIz3QB9kBXEACYQYoCAIo1qMfgjDAA9iGQwAjAAo4eJgEpM1ZAewxkGgHRtdGfYZtQIYXlCUwATGYtlrBmjWkhZCs5uHGiWXsgIivjyADYQpjHyJGpspsDanpKRIITIALZwAJ5sEABi8vJayAC8ejYk9uxqYTY2wMZqALJwYAAWplBwgvJ5zcgAfMgADKYArJbIdg5OrLjIAEQwFetUEuG29o5K-EIiIGKeNj6e1AD0t8gAEtAQAOT4yH0okIQAhFLqArFMoVDLUO4PAAqvWAH0ieQADsA4h8hgJFvx8AAadi8MDIBrnQY-ZDQKDyKCotjyPHIFS3AAsn1632AeQgv2QEK592QAAMBdyANoAUQASmKALp4dYigAeEAQeLEyAAUnAAG5wADKCGICPxpTgyLEOB2wvFUrwAGEhiB5Pi7HB0QjyQjoHIIB95MYTsJROi1E6BKRkK9gK9dMKADIAeQA4tKNlt5ObeQK+dygA

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following valid implementation of `A`:

```
const maybeFoo: A = {
    get b() {
        if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
            return "foo";
        }
        return undefined;
    }
};
```

Even if you check `if (maybeFoo.b) {...}`, that doesn't guarantee that the getter won't return `undefined` later when it's already passed to `f2`.